# How to remove double quotes from outside of an Array?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am taking data from the multiple select that gives me an array data. The data that I am getting is

```
{provinces: "["1","2"]"}
```

and when I stringify this data I got

```
{"provinces":"[\"1\",\"2\"]"}
```

But what I really want is

```
{"provinces":["1","2"]}
```

is there any way ?

Comment: I want to send this data to the server. when I send this to server it shows syntax error

Comment: "...The data that I getting is `{provinces: "["1","2"]"}` ..." how can you get this? This is invalid. The data you should get is `{provinces: ["1","2"]}`

Comment: I suggest you include more information on how you're ending up with what you describe as *an array data*, which is invalid from the start.

Answer (score 3):

use the `JSON.parse`

```js
var obj = {"provinces":"[\"1\",\"2\"]"} 

obj.provinces = JSON.parse(obj.provinces);
console.log(obj)
```